# Writing MemoryStream into SaveAs Dialogue Box in WInform

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an image which i want to write into itext Pdf file using c#.Here is my code to generate image from chart and write into itext pdf file.

```
Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);

    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        pdfDoc.Open();
        pieChart.SaveImage(stream, ChartImageFormat.Png);
        iTextSharp.text.Image chartImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(stream.GetBuffer());
        chartImage.ScalePercent(75f);
        pdfDoc.Add(chartImage);
    }
        pdfDoc.Close();
```

Now as per my reuirement i have to open this pdf file using Save as dialogue box.Here is the code by which i an trying to open this pdf file..

```
Stream myStream;
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Pdf files (*.pdf)|*.pdf|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 0;
        saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if ((myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
            {
                // Code to write the stream goes here.
                PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, myStream);
                myStream.Close();
            }
        }
```

But i am not able to get the pdf file.Dialogue Box is coming but i am not able to get the pdf file.
Please help me to resolve the issue .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to open the file wouldn't you use OpenFileDialog?

Comment: @Bearcat9425 I want to save pdfDoc at specified position thats why i have used SaveFileDialog

Answer (score 0):

**you need to save ur streambytes data to a file ...**

```
Stream myStream;
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Pdf files (*.pdf)|*.pdf|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 0;
        saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if ((myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
            {
                // Code to write the stream goes here.
                PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, myStream);
                myStream.Close();

using (FileStream file = new FileStream(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write,FileShare.ReadWrite)) {
   byte[] bytes = new byte[myStream.Length];
   ms.Read(bytes, 0, (int)myStream.Length);
   file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
   myStream.Close();
}

            }
        }
```

you can write stream data using streamwriter...

Comment: I am getting The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Ram\Desktop\correct.pdf' because it is being used by another process error at using (FileStream file = new FileStream(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))

Comment: try to save in d drive lets see what happed

Comment: You didn't declare the variable ms. What is it?

Comment: @Craig what do you mean by ms ?   `Memory Stream' ?